# How does Exchange message tracking deal with messages sent on behalf of other users?

Tags: exchange-2003

I'm dealing with an application that generates reports based on Exchange Message tracking logs (Exchange 2003).  When a user sends a message "on behalf of" another user, how is that logged?  Which user is logged as having sent the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I worked with Exchange 2003, but as I recall messages sent "On behalf Of" are sent utilizing the senders account, meaning userA sent on behalf of userB - the message would be tracked under userA. If however userA had full access rights to userB's mailbox and could actually Send As userB, then you would need to look under userB for message tracking purposes.

Comment: I was able to verify this myself with a quick test.  Thanks!